# How to fix CORS issue http request in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, angular2-services, angular5

I am new in Angular 5, and I want to send http request but it return CORS error in inspect element.

**Error**

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/account/create. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Below is my code:

```
postFormData(apiUrl: string, value: Object): Observable<any> {
const body = value;
const headers = new Headers();
const utcOffset = -(new Date().getTimezoneOffset());
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('utc-offset', utcOffset.toString());
headers.append('platform', 'WEB');
headers.append('app-version', '1.00');
headers.append('version', '1.0');
headers.append('accept', 'application/json');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

if (localStorage.getItem('user')) {
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  headers.append('token', user.token);
  headers.append('session', user.session);
}
// const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post(apiUrl, body, { headers: headers })
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleServerError);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide info about the web server (example.com in your case)? How is it setup?

Comment: i am not configured web server. in postman it is working

Comment: What do you get if you run `curl -X OPTIONS http://example.com/account/create -i` (replace with your actual server)

Comment: @samsonthehero thanks you so much for your reply

Comment: You adding headers for CORS as a client you can't do this the headers for CORS `Access-Control-*` has to come from your server so you need to fix the server code or get some one else to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

CORS is a tool employed by browsers to prevent one origin (localhost in your case) from accessing resources from another (example.com) without the server explicitly saying you can access it via CORS headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and others.

It is the server that needs to provide those headers in order for you to access its resources.

Mozilla has a good write up on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: i tried many things, install CORS extension etc

Comment: thanks for your answer, there was issue in server, they ware not allow to access-control-allow-origin

Comment: This answer has a good idea: `CORS` is managed server-side, not client-side.

Answer (score 1):

// Add CORS header.

```
Example :

const Url = 'http://localhost:3000/';
const headers = new Headers;
const body = JSON.stringify(
{
title: "data" 
});
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
this.http.post(Url, body, { headers: headers })
.pipe(map(res => res))
.catch(err => err);

// you can also use HTTP headers

import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

let header = new HttpHeaders();
header.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

Comment: doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have got http:// part in your apiUrl varialble send as an argument of postFormData function. That http:// part looks very essential while using HttpClient functions.

Answer (score 0):

CORS can only be managed server-side using the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

In your case, when serving Angular client side at `localhost:4200`, you have 2 options for the value of this header:

1. Add `*` -- this will enable all origins (not recommended in
   production environment)
2. Add `localhost:4200` (including the port!) -- that will explicit grant
   only the domain+port to your server